Sample size calculation clinical trial
I am trying to replicate a study about a randomized clinical trial. For this purpose I want to obtain the sample size calculation the authors did. In the paper they say:

Assuming a reduction of the outcome after treatment of 70% for the
treatment and 30% for placebo, 24 subjects per group were necessary to
discriminate differences in the reduction of primary outcome between
the 2 groups with a power of 80% and a significance level of 5%.

I want to obtain the same sample size calculation these people did.However, I cannot get to this number using a standard paired t-test, I think it is missing the SD. If this is not possible (as I suspect). Any suggestions?

Is that all the info you have? Are you just assuming they used a paired t-test, or do they say it explicitly? Do they mention at all the test they used? If it's a published paper, do you have some link to it? It may be useful to answer you, because there might be some info you're omitting and that is possibly crucial to give you a correct answer (you see what happened with the yet excellent answer by AdamO).

A percentage reduction can mean many things - it can mean effects for analyses of continuous outcomes on the logarithmic scale (like 70% off a sticker price). But because no standard deviation is invoked here, one immediately guesses that a binary endpoint is considered - such as the proportion of people experiencing a positive event like survival, remission, or recovery. Recall, the SD of a bernoulli event is determined by its mean, so no need to report the standard deviation in the assumptions of a power analysis.
There are several methods to analyze binary endpoints, such as a Chi-square test or Fisher's exact test. There are further considerations, such as whether continuity corrections are used, and how the authors did rounding, but very quickly I plug in the following to R and find:
> power.prop.test(power=0.8, sig.level = 0.05, p1 = 0.7, p2 = 0.3)

     Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation 

              n = 23.31288
             p1 = 0.7
             p2 = 0.3
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is number in *each* group

Which supports their choice of 24 in each group - 48 total with 1:1 assignment.

Thank you very much! That makes total sense! However, the primary outcome is a scale that ranges from 0 to 10. So assuming both groups have a 7 out of 10 at baseline, the treatment arm will be at 2.1 and control group at 4.9, respectively after treatment. Is their calculation then inappropriate for their problem? Thanks!

@adrian1121 this is a significant detail and omission from the post. Anyway, we already deduced a continuous approach is not used. Probably the score is dichotomized. I suggest you look into it further.
